# Медленная отрисовка DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

По событию загрузки формы выполняю следующий код

```
DoubleBuffered = true;
dgvPersCard.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
dgvPersCard.VirtualMode = true;

string error;
DataTable dt = _repository.GetAllCards2(out error);
if (error != string.Empty)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Помилка ініціалізації.\nТехнічна інформація: " + error, "Помилка");
  return;
}
dgvPersCard.DataSource = dt;
```

код выполняется быстро. Дальше происходит отрисовка формы и грида dgvPersCard, которая заметна на глаз. Приложил ссылку на видео. Подскажите, пожалуйста, это нормальная скорость работы грида или можно ускорить каким то образом? 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1broJsXdhXp_5Soo5_HCRAL6hyH-6MIPe

Comment: Может быть количество записей слишком велико?

Comment: 358 строк, я считаю, что это небольшое количество записей для грида

Comment: В чём смысл включить виртуализацию, но не использовать её и загонять сразу все данные?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Двойная буферизация поможет радикально ускорить отрисовку грида. Только включать её нужно именно у грида, а не у формы.

Свойство `DoubleBuffered` у компонента `DataGridView` является защищённым, поэтому напрямую его установить нельзя. Придётся создать унаследованный класс.

```
class DoubleBufferedDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool DoubleBuffered { get => true; }
}
```

Добавьте его в свой проект. Скомпилируйте. Далее используйте его вместо стандартного грида. Скорость отрисовки приятно удивляет.

---

В вашем коде, я вижу, включена виртуализация датагрида. Между тем вы ей не пользуетесь и загоняете в грид сразу все данные. Между тем, если её грамотно применить - обработать событие `NewRowNeeded` - то можно и с источниками данных в миллионы строк комфортно работать.

Comment: Спасибо добавил двойную буферизацию - помогло.

Comment: На VS 2015 работать не будет?

Comment: @tomato-magnet-regulato - почему нет-то?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, мало спал, затупил. все работает:) + бахнул