# DataGridView медленно работает после установки AutoSizeColumnsMode и/или AutoSizeRowsMode

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

После установки значений AutoSizeColumnsMode и/или AutoSizeRowsMode производительность рендеринга datagridView падает почти до 0 и это при 5 записях.

Очень медленно растягивается окно, клики по элементам отображаются с существенной задержкой. Кроме того он не корректно растягивает строки по высоте.
[image: Скриншот дата грид виев]
Как можно избавиться от данных проблем?

Comment: А в списках пассажиров там ничего нет сравнимого с по объемам Войной и Мир?

Comment: Нет. Там отсилы 7 строчек по типу ФИО\nФИО\n

Comment: А если так попробовать? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18291712/datagridview-autosizing-rows-with-wrapmode-set-lowers-performance-significantly

Comment: К чему привязан `DataGridView`? Хранятся ли все привязанные данные в памяти (не грузится ли какое-либо из свойств из БД)?

Comment: @default locale выягиваются из бд и ничего более `код` SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

            conn.Close();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`код`

Comment: @iluxa1810 тоже самое.

Comment: А если включить [двойную буферизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перестал пытаться разобраться почему оно медленно работает и начал ковыряться с выравниваем. Оказывается из за типа nchar в sql была огромная куча лишних пробелов в ячейках. Поменял на varchar - и о чудо решились обе проблемы).