# Заполнение progressbar во время выполнения метода

Tags: c#, парсер, async-await, task

Есть метод, который парсит столбец таблицы с сайта. При нажатии на кнопку метод выполняется более 1-2 секунд. Как можно сделать, чтобы прогресс бар заполнялся относительно завершения работы метода. 
Сам метод:

```
void GetClosePrices(string Active)
    {
        var url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+ Active + "/history?p=" + Active;
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url);

        HtmlNode collection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='Col1-1-HistoricalDataTable-Proxy']/section/div[2]/table/tbody");

        int rowscount = collection.ChildNodes.Count + 1;            

        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn { HeaderText = Active, CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()});

        if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowscount);

        for (int i = 0; i < collection.ChildNodes.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            var nodes = collection.SelectSingleNode("tr[" + i + "]/td[5]");
            if (nodes != null)
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1].Value = nodes.InnerText.Replace('.', ',');

        }
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Comment: Что именно происходит долго: загрузка данных или их обработка? Если первое, то запрогрессить это можно лишь в том случае, если класс/метод загрузки предоставляет колбэк с процентом. Если такого нет, то ищите другой способ загрузки. Если второе, то запускайте код в отдельном потоке/задаче, при этом обращаться к контролам нужно через `Invoke`.

Comment: `HtmlWeb` - это из библиотеки `HtmlAgilityPack`? Этот класс, вроде, не умеет асинхронно выполнять работу. Стало быть, для отображения прогресса загрузки не подойдет.

Comment: Кстати, если у вас проблемы с медленной отрисовкой `DataGridView`, [включите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217) у него двойную буферизацию.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov 1) Происходит долгая загрузка данных. 2) Да, использую библиотеку HtmlAgilityPack. Не подскажите как сделать колбэк с процентом? Заранее спасибо

Comment: Загружать данные с помощью `WebClient`, например, а уже потом передавать их в HAP.