# Загрузка таблицы одновременно с формой

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, datagridview

**Суть проблемы:** при загрузке формы выполнялся запрос на выборку из таблицы на большое кол-во записей и при открытии формы ничего не появлялось на секунд 30, т.к. выполняется этот запрос, но потом появляется форма, что логично, но я решил не пугать пользователя такой долгой паузой

**Как я пытался решить:** Делал этот запрос на событие `Shown`, но появлялся кусок формы и она просто зависала, тоже не то

**Что я делаю сейчас:** Решил реализовать выполнение запроса через поток, пока будет загружаться форма, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
public partial class RunnersInfo : Form
{
    //Создание потока, в котором метод на запрос из БД
    Thread TableLoad = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DBConnection.GetRunners));

     private void RunnersControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Запуск потока
        TableLoad.Start();
        //Присваивание результата dataGridView, dtRunners переменная, 
        которая содержит результат запроса;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DBConnection.dtRunners;
        //Прочий код
    }
}
```

Но возникла следующая проблема `dataGridView1.DataSource = DBConnection.dtRunners;` выполняется раньше чем сам запрос и в итоге мы получаем пустую таблицу.

Я попытался воспользоваться `TableLoad.Join();` но это привело к самому началу и процесс был заморожен, до выполнения окончания выполнения `TableLoad`, что логично

Также я пытался объединить `DBConnection.GetRunners()` и `dataGridView1.DataSource = DBConnection.dtRunners;` в один метод но возникла другая ошибка:

```
public partial class RunnersInfo : Form
{
    Thread TableLoad = new Thread(new ThreadStart(LoadRunners));

    private void RunnersControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableLoad.Start();
        //Код
    }

    private static void LoadRunners()
    {
        DBConnection.GetRunners()
        //Ошибка: Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства 
          RunnersInfo.dataGridView1 требуется ссылка на объект.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DBConnection.dtRunners;
    }
}
```

Да, я не знаю, как указать ссылку на этот dataGridView1 -.-
Ну вот, как-то так

Comment: А сколько именно данных загружается? Многие тысячи строк? Или сам sql-запрос долго выполняется? Удобно ли будет пользователю копаться в таком количестве? Обычно для работы с большим количеством данных используют [виртуальный режим](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control) грида (с подгрузкой данных).

Comment: Вы не можете взаимодействовать с формой их статического класса, если только не передадите туда ссылку. В вашем сллучае просто сделайте метод нестатичным, хотя будут другие проблемы.

Comment: Ещё советую сделать [двойную буферизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217) грида. Но это мелочь.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Многие тысячи строк, ну предусмотрен поиск , сортировки и фильтрации, для большего удобства, хорошо спасибо, почитаю про виртуальный режим

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте используем современные средства: `Task` и `async/await`.
Можно использовать события `Load` или `Shown` - неважно.

```
private async void Form1_LoadAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataTable = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // здесь загрузка данных из БД
        return dt;
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

    dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
}
```

Обратите внимание на сигнатуру метода: он помечен `async`.

Загрузка данных будет выполнена в отдельном потоке (задаче). Форма при это зависать не будет. После завершения загрузки будет выполнена привязка.

Параметр `LongRunning` создаст новый поток, а не возьмёт поток из пула. Это желательно, т. к. нам известно, что мы выполняем длительное действие. Именно поэтому используется метод `Factory.StartNew` вместо более лаконичного `Task.Run`.

---

Желательно сделать полностью асинхронную загрузку, вместо создания отдельного потока/задачи, но это существенно сложнее и код будет громоздким.