# Как ускорить добавление строк в datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Хочу добавить 100тыс строк с 5-6 колонками в grid. Если делать через `datagridview.Rows.Add()` это занимает много времени.

Временное решение - привязать через `binding`

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<DB>(lst.Take(1000000).ToList());
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Вот первичный код, который надо оптимизировать

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count(); i++)
  {
     var row1 = new string[] { lst[i].Ves, lst[i].Tovar, lst[i].Mnn, lst[i].Category, lst[i].Tsena, lst[i].Ostatok };
     dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row1);
     dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1].HeaderCell.Value = i;
  }
```

Comment: 100 000 строк? Зачем?

Comment: @tym32167 логично ватсон) Чтобы просмотреть. Дальше искать по ним. Фильтровать. Ну и т.д

Comment: @tym32167 ну и хочу в header строки слева добавить данные. Через биндинг у меня нет такой возможности

Comment: я бы добавил пейджинг, 100к строк могут нехило подвесить клиента со слабой машиной. Ну или хотя бы [юзайте виртуализацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control)

Comment: В дополнение к пейджингу/виртуализации включите [двойную буферизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217) у грида. Но это лишь ускорит его отрисовку и устранит мерцание.

Comment: Ещё можно попробовать вот этот [способ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/778133/5045688) - перед добавлением большого количества строк отключаем отрисовку грида, после - включаем. Но опять же, при ста тысячах строк - это как мёртвому припарка. Так что только пейджинг и виртуализация вам реально помогут.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проблема в том что метод addrow занимает много времени

Comment: даже если не отображать грид, это занимает время