# Тормозит dataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Поместил `dataGridView` в `wiforms` и создал таблицу 5 колонок / 1000 строк
Первую колонку полностью заполнил данными `string` - строки из 10-15 символов, а остальные колонки пустые.

А спускаюсь ползунком в самый низ таблицы - на `winforms` - она притормаживает - даже ползунок замедляется(

Это нормально для такой таблицы ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скачки при спуске - ничего больше не выполняется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очевидно, нужно сделать пагинацию, т.е. выводить частями информацию, а не весь массив данных сразу загружать в DGV.

Comment: Или попробуйте включить виртуализацию

Comment: Для начала попробуйте включить [двойную буферизацию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, это здорово помогло!