# Проблема с отображением Details в ListView C# VirtualMode

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Приложение на **Winforms**.

Использую `VirtualMode` для отображения данных в `ListView`. Сначала создаю столбцы.

```
for (int i = 0; i < lStr; i++)
{
    dataTable.Columns.Add(i.ToString(), "Col#" + i.ToString());            
}
            
dataTable.VirtualListSize = showArray.Length;
```

Для заполнения использую событие `RetreveVirtualItem`.

```
private void dataTable_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item = new ListViewItem(showArray[e.ItemIndex].ToString());
}
```

В режиме представления `Details` получаю такую ошибку.

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** "В режиме VirtualMode событие RetrieveVirtualListItem для ListView требует наличия подэлемента представления списка для каждого столбца ListView."

В других режимах отображения данной ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Используйте `DataGridView`. Это лучший выход.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov приложение обрабатывает относительно большие объемы данных, `DataGridView` очень долго отрисовывает.

Comment: Включите у грида двойную буферизацию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809144/184217

Comment: `очень долго отрисовывает` и вы с этим крнечно же не стали разбираться.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, это действительно ускорило отрисовку, но неужели `ListView` такой проблемный, что лучше использовать `DataGridView`?

Comment: @aepot во-первых, что значит не стал разбираться, я разобрался перейдя на `ListView`. Во-вторых, проблема с `DataGridView`, не только в долгой отрисовке, но и в параметре `FillWeight`, который не может быть более `2^16`. А в программе возможна, редка, но возможна ситуация с потребностью больше чем в 65К столбцах.

Comment: В таком случае я бы использовал WPF и `DataGrid` с виртуализацией, у меня 2кк строк тянуло, не кашляло. Что касается 64к столбцов - то это странные данные, вы никогда столько столбцов не поместите на экран, а следовательно и отображать такое количество столбцов не имеет никакого смысла. Что касается `ListView`, то в показанном коде нет причины для данного исключения. Либо вы показали не весь код, либо проблема в другом месте.

Comment: Переходить на WPF не вариант, потому что есть уже почти готовое приложение на WindowsForms и `DataGridView` только один его модуль. Насчёт `ListView` это весь код, относящий к нему, исключение выскакивает в событии `RetrieveVirtualItem` на создании нового `ListViewItem` только в режиме `Details`, с остальными режимами все нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В ошибке всё сказано: требуется подэлемент (SubItem) для каждого столбца.

Нужно примерно следующее:

```
private void DataTable_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
        item.SubItems.Add("тут данные для столбца");

    e.Item = item;
}
```